# In how much time a certain sum will be become $81$ times of itself given the following conditions?

Tags: numerical-methods

> If a certain sum of money triples in of itself in $7$ years.In how much time it will become $81$ times of itself.

MyApproach:

For First Time:$3^1$ in $7$ years.

To  get $81$ times=>$3^4$=($7$*$4$)$28$ years will be needed in every $7$ years interval.

so $28$ years is the Ans.

> Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct, provided this is basic level mathematics, the way you have stated the question. However I don't understand what you mean by "28 years will be needed in 7 years.

and in 1 year =28/7=4 years."

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Everything up to the words "28 years will be needed" is perfect.  You should have stopped there.

Everything after the words "28 years will be needed" is meaningless.  WHat were you even trying to say about in 1 year it is 4 years???

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Lets say in year 0 you have $d. We know in year 7 you have 3d dollars. Now this triples in 7 years, so you have 3*3d dollars in year 14.  Now this triples in 7 years, so you have 3*3*3d dollars in year 21.   Now this triples in 7 years, so you have 3*3*3*3d = 81d dollars.

We repeated this process of waiting 7 years 4 times, so 7*8 = 28. This is how we get the correct answer at the simplest level.